# подключение, просмотр и редактирование файловой системы android при помощи python

Tags: python, android, файловая-система

Телефон на Android, подключен к ПК в режиме передачи файлов. На телефоне и sd-карте большое количество фотографий, которые необходимо упорядочить. Возможно ли как-то подключиться к файловой системе телефона и sd-карте при помощи python?

Модуль os не сработал:
код

```
print(os.listdir(r'Этот компьютер\MI PLAY\disk\DCIM'))
```

выдает ошибку FileNotFoundError.